# How do you install playground books on iPad?

Tags: ipad, swift

I found a playground book from Apple online called "Talking To The Live View". It's an updated playground from the 2016 WWDC. I want to install it on my iPad and try it out. Further, I want to experiment with building my own playground books and installing them on my iPad.

I'm a licensed iOS developer, and know how to install apps on iOS devices, but despite searching for a couple of hours I have not been able to figure out how to install playground books onto my iPad other than the ones that magically get listed from Apple.

Comment: Have you seen [this Playground Book article](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/building-swift-playground-books/) from Ash Furrow?  It goes into detail on how to build the books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that if you use AirDrop to send the Playground book to yourself, iOS offers to open it in the Swift Playgrounds app.

Comment: Glad the article helped!